# Alternatives to MySQL Utilities

Tags: mysql

Are there alternatives to these [MySQL utilities](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-utilities/tree/master)? These look valuable but then are on Python 2.7 which I cannot even run now. I think it is related to [this](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/utilities/) which is already archived.

Comment: Which utilities do you use the most?

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct replacement for all the MySQL utilities. Some tools are available in the MySQL community for some of these features.

- [MySQL Shell](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/) has utility functions that duplicate some of the tools in MySQL Utilities. This is an official MySQL product, but installed separately from MySQL Community Server.

  I think the intention was for MySQL Shell to be the successor to
  MySQL Utilities, but not all functionality has been reimplemented.

  MySQL Shell is supposed to be extensible, so there is an opportunity for it to be a platform for community tools.
- [Sys Schema](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sys-schema.html) is part of the default MySQL Community Server distribution. You should definitely learn this.
- [Percona Toolkit](https://www.percona.com/software/database-tools/percona-toolkit) is still maintained by Percona. I've used this frequently.
- [Common Schema](https://github.com/shlomi-noach/common_schema) and [OpenArk Kit](https://github.com/shlomi-noach/openarkkit) had a number of useful tools, but the author has [reduced his involvement in open source projects](https://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/reducing-my-oss-involvement-and-how-it-affects-orchestrator-gh-ost). The last release of Common Schema was in 2016, and the last release of OpenArk Kit was in 2013.